# Can I fix TypeScript imports to use only @ns/pkg instead of @ns/pkg/subdir/xy automatically?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, import

I have imports like this:

```
import { some } from '@namespace/pkg/some/other';
```

The package has proper index file now, so I want to change all imports to:

```
import { some } from '@namespace/pkg';
```

There are many imports to change. Can I automate this using VsCode or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind.. VScode mass replace can do it using regexps.

You might also need the auto import plugin to merge all the @some/pkg imports, but recent VSCode versions might be able automatically do that.